# SP2010 Using Modal Dialog for Forms : Beginner Questions

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, form, modal-dialog, dialog-framework

So I am trying to figure out how to use some java script in order to use a modal dialog to display new item form. The below is what I have thus far, but its not working and I am not sure what portion is wrong, missing, etc.

```
//use a button for example
<input type="button" value="Launch Dialog" id="myDialog" onclick="openDiaForm();"/>

//inside script tags under PlaceHolder Main
function openDiaForm()
{
   var diaOptions = SP.UI.create_DialogOptions();
   diaOptions.url = 'http://mySPDev/sites/jQueryPractice/Lists/ExampleList/NewForm.aspx?ID=' + 1 + '&IsDlg=1';
   diaOptions.url += "?Source=" + document.url;
   diaOptions.width = 400;
   diaOptions.height = 300;
   diaOptions.title = "My Custom Dialog Form";
   diaOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallBack);
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(diaOptions);
}

function CloseCallBack(result, returnValue)
{
   if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
   {
      alert('clicked ok because I do not know how to work with result yet!');
   }
   else
   {
      alert('click cancel because I still do not know how to work with result!');
   }
}
```

So basically I am just looking at learning how to open a new item form for a list in a modal dialog. I have yet to get to working with the result in order to do this, but for now I can't seem to get the dialog to come up. Again, I found an example and am trying to learn from what I have but need some help; any help with this is greatly appreciated as always!

**EDIT**: forgot to mention that I do have the script reference to `sp.js` in the page; have other javascript/jquery actions working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is working. There were 2 errors which I have commented in the code.

```
//use a button for example
<input type="button" value="Launch Dialog" id="myDialog" onclick="openDiaForm();"/>

//inside script tags under PlaceHolder Main
function openDiaForm()
{
   //Use SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions() instead of SP.UI.create_DialogOptions()
   //The name of the method starts with a "$"
   var diaOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
   diaOptions.url = 'http://mySPDev/sites/jQueryPractice/Lists/ExampleList/NewForm.aspx?ID=' + 1 + '&IsDlg=1';
   diaOptions.url += "?Source=" + document.url;
   diaOptions.width = 400;
   diaOptions.height = 300;
   diaOptions.title = "My Custom Dialog Form";
   //Use Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallBack) instead of function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallBack);
   //The createDelegate method is part of the Function object. "function" is used to define a new function.
   diaOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallBack);
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(diaOptions);
}

function CloseCallBack(result, returnValue)
{
   if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
   {
      alert('clicked ok because I do not know how to work with result yet!');
   }
   else
   {
      alert('click cancel because I still do not know how to work with result!');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This script should open a popup Window but you will need to update the Urls and the list id's to suit your enviroment.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function silentCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
}


function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Operation Successful!'); 
SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); 
}

var orderPrinterOptions= { 
url: "/xxx/PrinterList/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={5BF16642-B7C4-4E54-  990D-E0E040F97DA9}&RootFolder=", 
title: "Order a Printer", 
allowMaximize: true, 
showClose: true, 
width: 650, 
height: 525,
dialogReturnValueCallback: silentCallback}; 

function orderPrinter() 
{SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(orderPrinterOptions);} 
</script> 

<a href="javascript:orderPrinter()"><img width="234" height="232" alt="orderprinter.png" src="/xxx/PrinterList/Shared%20Documents/orderprinter.png" border="0" style="margin: 5px; width: 219px; height: 219px"/></a>
<div class="ms-rteFontSize-3" style="text-align:  center">Order&#160;New&#160;Printer&#160;</div>
```

**You can enbed all this code directly into a content editor webpart.** I hope this helps!